# Most isolated point on 2d map - algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have a set of points, and need to know which one has the farthest euclidean distance from any other points.

In order to get this point, I have every distance for all my points, make an average, and take the biggest average as the farthest point.

Is there any faster way to find out that point ?

Comment: Are you set on this definition of "Isolated" and want a faster algorithm for it?  Or are you asking if there is a better/faster definition of "most isolated"?

Comment: First you have to define 'most distant'. Do you mean the point with the furthest distance to the 'center' for some definition of center? Or do you e.g. mean the point with the greatest distance to its nearest neighbour?

Comment: for performance improvent:

Be sure that the distance between 2 points is calculated once, because dist(p1,p2) = dist(p2,p1)

Comment: I'm looking for a faster algorithm.

I mean the point with the greatest distance to its nearest neighbours.

Comment: You should clarify that in the question. It sounds like you want the to average the distances to *all* other points to measure "isolation", which is different than "furthest nearest neighbors".

Comment: Maybe build a k-d tree of your points.  You can use that to find the nearest neighbor for each point and take the largest of all those.  You should get a O(log n) instead of a O(n*n) algorithm that way.

Comment: @VaughnCato You meant О(n * log n) algorithm, not O(log n).

Comment: Oh also, if you mean euclidean distance (as measure of distance) it should be sufficient to use the square of the distance.

Comment: if you need an answer, you should edit your post and clarify on what exactly your are looking for.

Comment: @ArunR I'm not sure what you meant by that. Isn't using the square of the distance remains an O(n^2) algorithm ?

Comment: @Sgluive: It's faster to compute the square of the distance than the actual distance, which reduces the constant factor but doesn't reduce the runtime complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: @Sgluive But "*the point with the greatest distance to its nearest neighbours*" is completely different from the definition of "most isolated" that you are using in your question above, which is "*the point with the least average distance to all of its neighbors*".  Please carify, **which is it**?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have suggested, build a [KD-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) for all N points. This will take `O(N logN)` time. For each point find the nearest neighbor, which for a single point can be done in `O(logN)`. For all `N` points, you can find the most isolated point by finding the minimum of this set in `O(N logN)`.

In addition, you now have a handy KD-tree for other distance based queries.

Comment: My understanding is that building a k-d tree in O(n log n) time is tricky, and most implementations are actually O(n log^2 n).  The nearest neighbor lookup is typically O(log n) for randomly distributed points.  If the distribution isn't random, it can be much worse.  You also have to use a tweaked version of the algorithm, or the nearest neighbor lookup for each point will simply return the same point.  It's certainly a win if you have additional queries to do against the tree.  If not, you might want to try a simpler higher-complexity algorithm first.

Comment: @Hooked "Note that x does not have to be a preexisting point in P" How will Kd Trees work is the point is already present. It is returning the same point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to do better than O(n^2).  I wouldn't be surprised if there is a way to do better by pre-processing the points into a spatial partition structure, but those are generally only useful if you're doing many calculations.

But even with O(n^2), you can do a few optimizations to reduce the constant factor enough that a 100,000 points can be checked in a couple of seconds.

The basic algorithm:

```
nearest_of_most_isolated = 0
for every point A {
  nearest = infinity
  for every point B != A
    nearest = min(nearest, distance(A, B));
  if (nearest > nearest_of_most_isolated) {
    nearest_of_most_isolated = nearest
    most_isolated = A
  }
}
return most_isolated;
```

Opportunities for optimization:

1. You can have an early-out in the inner loop.  If `nearest becomes < nearest_of_most_isolated`, then you can break out of the inner loop because you can already rule this point out.  That's a pretty dramatic improvement.
2. You could memoize the distance calculations, but that requires O(n^2) memory.  By being clever, you can cut that in half by taking advantage of symmetry (the distance from A->B is the same as the distance from B->A).  But the distance calculation is very simple, so it may not be worth the effort.
3. Since you're just comparing the relative distances, you can use the squares of the distances, which are faster to compute than the actual distances.  This further reduces the value of #2.
4. If you have multiple processors or cores, you could parallelize this by running *n* instances of the algorithm across *n* subsets of the candidate cities (the inner loop must still hit them all) and then doing a follow-up pass over the individual results.  This is probably worthwhile if the number of points is extremely large.

Comment: @VaughnCato already provided O(nlogn) solution with kDtrees for the problem, where the distance to the nearest neighbour is maximized.